# C++ pointers to consecutive vector elements are paradoxical

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I want to find out the "distances" between locations of consecutive vector elements in the memory. So I try the following code

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec(3);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
    {
        cout << &vec[i+1] - &vec[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The result are unsurprisingly two `1`s. However, when I try printing the individual pointers:

```
vector<int> vec(3);
for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
{
    cout << &vec[i] << endl;
}
```

The result is

```
01485048
0148504C
01485050
```

So the difference between two consecutive elements should be `4`. Seemingly a contradiction to the previous result. What goes wrong here?

Comment: 1. Why are you doing this? 2. Have you ever seen  `++` applied to a pointer?

Comment: @n.m. 1. I want to make sure pointers of consecutive elements are also consecutive, so that `*(&vec[i]+1)` points to `vec[i+1]`. 2. Not exactly sure what you mean but I think I was applying `++` to the index of an element instead of the pointer, although I think it will also work for pointers.

Comment: So you have found exactly what you wanted to verify. Are you surprised that `(&vec[i]+1)-(&vec[i])==1`?

Comment: @n.m. No but I was surprised that `&vec[0] =  01485048` and `&vec[1] = 0148504C` and `&vec[1]-&vec[0]` is `1` instead of `4`. Now my confusion has been clarified. As the accepted answer says, I am not supposed to treat pointer values as ordinary integer objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculating a difference between two pointers returns **number of objects** between them - that's why you cannot perform arithmetic on two pointers of different types. If you want to know the distance of **bytes** between them, either cast both pointers to `char*` or multiply the result of substraction by `sizeof(your_type)`.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing particular to `vector`. C++ pointer arithmetic (and iterator arithmetic) is done in terms of elements. And indeed, `vec[i+1]` and `vec[i]` are one element apart.

One element here happens to be 4 bytes, which is what you see when printing the bit pattern of the pointers. You can double-check this with `sizeof(vec[0])`

Comment: Yeah I know int should have four bytes. But the problem is, why the first result is two 1's? Shouldn't they be two 4's instead?

Comment: @Barry ok thanks. I finally understand what it means by the help of an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You should cast pointers to `uintptr_t` so substraction will yield amount of bytes in between them:

```
cout << (reinterpret_cast< uintptr_t >(&vec[i+1]) - reinterpret_cast< uintptr_t >(&vec[i])) << endl;
```

Comment: Eww. You could also multiply the result by `sizeof(*pointer)`, which is portable (and far less ugly, but that's subjective)

Comment: @MSalters Not really, just imagine the situations when two pointers to `uint32_t` point at memory blocks that are 13 bytes away from each other.

Comment: That would be illegal, as you're not allowed to subtract pointers unless they both point to the same array. And clearly there's no `uint32_t[N]` with 13 bytes between elements (ignoring 32 bits bytes for a moment).

Comment: @MSalters *That would be illegal* is exactly what i'm talking about. Method with casting to intptr is universal.

Comment: Well, universal in the sense that it produces a number, not in the sense that it is meaningful. In particular, it's not necessarily suitable for arithmetic. E.g. you're not even guaranteed that `uintptr_t` has the same endianness as `int*` (!)